# How does imblearn apply the transformations during prediction?

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, python-3.x, pipelines

Let's say I have a sklearn pipeline that:

1. Imputes the data
2. Randomly oversamples the minority class

```py
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler

pipeline = Pipeline(
    [('1', SimpleImputer(strategy='median'),
     ('2', RandomOverSampler(random_state=0)),
     ('estimator', <Some Logistic Regression>)
    ]
)
```

I can then fit this to my training set `pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)` and the random oversampler should properly identify the class to sample. What if I try to predict i.e `pipeline.predict(X_test)`? Since there are no classes, does the random oversampler still apply? I would expect the imputer to apply regardless but what about `RandomOverSampler`?

Thank you

Comment: Could you clarify the question please? What do you mean by "since there are no classes"?

Comment: So when I do `pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)`, I am providing the classes so `RandomOverSampler` knows which class is the minority and resamples the data appropriately. When I predict, `pipeline.predict()` I am not (cannot) providing the classes so `RandomOverSampler` has no way of telling which is the minority class.

Comment: okay. 1.I would assume it works like any other fit method where it keeps the learned statistics from train and then apply on the test.2. Even if it doesn't, i would not want to to know the classes in test data and perform good despite the class imbalance problem since in training i specifically made it learn this?

Answer (score 1):

You generally shouldn't apply resampling to the test set (although there are some differing opinions on whether to do so on various levels of validation data).  imblearn has its own version of the pipeline to accomplish this; in particular, [the pipeline docs say](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#imblearn.pipeline.Pipeline):

> The samplers are only applied during fit.